# error display date

Tags: android

i want to get the date and display in my activity
i do this code today but works wrong

```
    private int mYear;
        private int mMonth;
        private int mDay;
String Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    Date = mDay + "-" + mMonth + "-" + mYear;
```

it dispay `18-11-2012`
which is wrong 
but it confuse me why the month display 11 even if the month is 12 
what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it, with Calendar and SimpleDateFormat to easily format output as you wish.

```
    Calendar myCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    formatter.setCalendar(myCalendar);
    String dateString = formatter.format(myCalendar.getTime());
```

Outputs:
`19-12-2012`

Answer (score 0):

```
c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

return the index of the month (I.e. January is 0). So nothing wrong, that's the API...

**EDIT**

```
String date = mDay + "-" + (mMonth+1) + "-" + mYear;
```

will display the date correctly.

Please note that the Java API provide the [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) API to display date in various format (depending on user's locale). It's often a better choice to use it.

Comment: so how can show to user the right number of month after display it in text cause it will confuse if he so 11 month and the actually month is 12

Answer (score 0):

In Java numbers of mounths start from 0

Comment: how can i display it from 1 ?

Comment: Date = mDay + "-" + (++mMonth) + "-" + mYear;